# how to add image path in seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I need to add an image path in to my seeds.rb. All my images is in assets/images/courses
I dont understand how to correctly add image path to my course in seeds.rb

```
Course.create!(
    name: "Art",
    description: "In this beginner's art class learners will meet to create nature inspired artwork!
                Perfect class for Pre-Kindergarten, Kindergarten, 1st grade & 2nd grade artists
                (UK: Reception, Year 1, Year 2, Year 3)- with science & a touch of geography.",
    tags: "#art #image #kids",
    ages: "4 - 13",
    minsize: 4,
    maxsize: 7,
    duration: 45,
    price: 10,
    image_url: "images/courses/art1.jpg",
    )
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in the `seeds.rb` file, but in the view where you accessing that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to save the relative path to that image to render it later in your views, you could just use the `image_path` method that will pull that image from the rails assets folder

seeds.rb doesn't autoload those helpers, so you need to reference it from the ActionController::Base class like this in order to make it work:

```rb
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('courses/art1.jpg')
```

So in your example you need to write it like this:

```rb
Course.create!(
  name: "Art",
  description: "In this beginner's art class learners will meet to create nature inspired artwork!
              Perfect class for Pre-Kindergarten, Kindergarten, 1st grade & 2nd grade artists
              (UK: Reception, Year 1, Year 2, Year 3)- with science & a touch of geography.",
  tags: "#art #image #kids",
  ages: "4 - 13",
  minsize: 4,
  maxsize: 7,
  duration: 45,
  price: 10,
  image_url: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('courses/art1.jpg')
)
```

#### Unrelated but maybe useful information

If at some point you change your course model to support image upload, then you will find it handy to have the actual FilePath to the file, so you can use it as a file in your seed code:

```rb
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'pic1.jpg')
```

`Rails.root` will return a [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) with the absolute path to your rails project.
The `join` method can take any number of arguments and it will append them to the pathname to create the new path.

Having the pathname is useful for File methods and image uploads implementations